# Get dates of a day of week in a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, generate-series

I need a function in PostgreSQL that accepts a date range and returns the dates inside the date range that are Mondays. Anybody have an idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way should be to find the first Monday and generate a series in steps of 7 days:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_mondays(dr daterange)
  RETURNS TABLE (day date) AS
$func$
SELECT generate_series(a + (8 - EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM a)::int) % 7
                     , z
                     , interval '7 days')::date
FROM  (
   SELECT CASE WHEN lower_inc(dr) THEN lower(dr) ELSE lower(dr) + 1 END AS a
        , CASE WHEN upper_inc(dr) THEN upper(dr) ELSE upper(dr) - 1 END AS z
   ) sub
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

- The subquery extracts start (`a`) and end (`z`) of the range, adjusted for inclusive and exclusive bounds [with range functions.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)
- The expression `(8 - EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM a)::int) % 7` returns the number of days until the next monday. `0` if it's Monday already. [The manual about `EXTRACT().`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)
- [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) can iterate any given interval - 7 days in this case. The result is a `timestamp`, so we cast to `date`.
- Only generates Mondays in the range, no `WHERE` clause needed.

Call:

```
SELECT day FROM f_mondays('[2014-04-14,2014-05-02)'::daterange);
```

Returns:

```
day
----------
2014-04-14
2014-04-21
2014-04-28
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6726d/6)

Answer (score 3):

```
create function f(dr daterange)
returns setof date as $$
    select d::date
    from generate_series(
        lower(dr), upper(dr), interval '1 day'
    ) s (d)
    where
        extract(dow from d) = 1 and
        d::date <@ dr;
    ;
$$ language sql;

select f(daterange('2014-01-01', '2014-01-20'));
     f      
------------
 2014-01-06
 2014-01-13
```

Comment: Nice and simple. A minor gripe: When working with a `daterange` inclusive / exclusive borders should be observed.