# Get the count of distinct userids for last couple of days

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, distinct, aggregate-functions

Let's say the last 7 days for this table:

```
Userid   Download time
Rab01    2020-04-29 03:28
Klm01    2020-04-29 04:01
Klm01    2020-04-30 05:10
Rab01    2020-04-29 12:14
Osa_3    2020-04-25 09:01
```

Following is the required output:

```
Count  Download_time
1      2020-04-25
2      2020-04-29
1      2020-04-30
```

Comment: For `Download_time` , the count should be 1 right? Is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah sorry....corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with PostgreSQL. You also tagged Redshift, which forked at Postgres 8.2, a long time ago. There may be discrepancies ..

Since you seem to be happy with standard ISO format, a simple cast to date would be most efficient:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT userid) AS "Count"
     , download_time::date AS "Download_Day"
FROM   tbl
WHERE  download_time >= CURRENT_DATE - 7
AND    download_time <  CURRENT_DATE
GROUP  BY 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2a063d81d7133c217f0519470b43a661)*

`CURRENT_DATE` is standard SQL and works for both [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and [Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_DATE_function.html). Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)

About the "last 7 days": I took the last 7 *whole* days (excluding today - necessarily incomplete), with syntax that can use a plain index on `(download_time)`. Related:

- [Get dates of a day of week in a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047091/get-dates-of-a-day-of-week-in-a-date-range/23049937#23049937)
- [Slow LEFT JOIN on CTE with time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221842/slow-left-join-on-cte-with-time-intervals/50224911?noredirect=1#comment87491850_50224911)
- [Interval (days) in PostgreSQL with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123409/interval-days-in-postgresql-with-two-parameters/31127978#31127978)

Ideally, you have a composite index on `(download_time, userid)` (and fulfill some preconditions) to get very fast [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans). See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

`count(DISTINCT ...)` is typically slow. For big tables with many duplicates, there are faster techniques. Disclose your exact setup and cardinalities if you need to optimize performance.

If the actual data type is `timestamptz`, not just `timestamp`, you also need to define the time zone defining day boundaries. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

About the optional short syntax `GROUP BY 2`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

About capitalization of identifiers:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Found it insightful.Thanks

Comment: now()::date doesn't work in redshift ....getdate() will work here.

Comment: @ashwini571: I switched to `CURRENT_DATE`, which works for both. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function for get day only part from datetime and use it for grouping.

The query may be next:

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct Userid) as Count, -- get unuque users count
    to_char(date_trunc('day', Download_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Download_Day -- convert time do day
FROM table
WHERE DATE_PART('day', NOW() - Download_time) < 7 -- last 7 days
GROUP BY Download_Day; -- group by day
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=105b61d4e99e382c64f1e1e66f7c44a3)